# Bundle and publish client-side web code on NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a Javascript file. Let's say the contents of it are this:

```js
let myCoolAlert = (str) => {
    alert(str)
}

// in a different js file (SO doesn't allow you to cross-file as far as I know
myCoolAlert('Hello World!')
```

I already hosted the JS file on a CDN. Now, I want it to be automatically hosted locally by whoever installed it if you install it via NPM. Is there a way to do this?

Also, I noticed that to do the same using Socket.io, you have to pass Socket.io to the HTTP/HTTPS server you created. Will I have to do this also? (I would prefer not).

Thanks!

### Edit:

I am trying to make a better alert system (like sweetalert). I coded it in Javascript and works when using it through the CDN. However, I also want users to be able to install this via NPM (kind of like SweetAlert? I am not sure about that last statement however because I do not use it). When they install it with NPM, it's obviously going to be useless because it is for the browser. However, I want them to either:

1. Automatically have the source code needed available at a URL like `localhost:3000(or server name)/betterAlert.js` and be able to use that URL as a script in the HTML files
2. OR, have the user pass the HTTP or HTTPS server they created to the module (like socket.io does) and have it automatically host it from there.

### Please note:

The code I am trying to bundle is native to the web. Will it still work with a bundler like webpack?

Is this possible? Thanks again.

Comment: So you want the to have an option for deploying the static page with JavaScript downloaded locally when your package is installed? I don't think that's doable because the static file needs to be in your package. You can try to include a dev-server that can host the file locally in which case, you can still keep using your CDN and have the dev-server point to the cached CDN page URL.

Comment: @AbrarHossain thanks for responding! I don't want the user's to use the CDN if they install it via NPM, I want them to host it so they can use their own version (instead of the CDN's). Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to add a webserver to your package. You can use the [`http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) which is part of node, or you can use some additional modules like [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). But seem like quite an overkill ...

Comment: Yes. You can check the `http-server` package. It can quickly deploy a static site on localhost.

Comment: @derpirscher would instead piggybacking off of the user's http server instead be a more viable option?

Comment: @derpirscher e.g. what socket.io does: `let server = require('http').createServer( app );
let io = require( 'socket.io' )( server );`

Comment: Well, of course if the user has a webserver installed. But how would you know that during the installation of your package? And how would you know where to place your files? ...

Comment: @derpirscher I wouldn't, so maybe automatic install isn't a good idea?

Comment: If you could describe your use case, what you are trying to do with your "package" and what's the purpose of serving it? Then we might be able to help you better. If you package is intended to be some part in website development, then someone using it will probably already have a webserver installed ...

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for your feedback. I will add that info to the question!

Comment: @derpirscher sorry for taking so long, I edited it. THanks!

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/ does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense at all. You are building a module to be included into websites/webapps by webdevelopers, right? Why on earth would a webdeveloper using your module want to fire up an additional webserver to host your module? The typical workflow is to either install your module within the website/webapp project so it can be served by what ever webserver is already used during development or including it from a CDN.

Comment: I agree with what Derpirscher says, if you want a library to be available by CDN or by installing it with NPM, you have to "transpile" it with webpack for example in different versions (browser or ESM).

Comment: @derpirscher the first scenario that you included is what I want. (I want the module to be installed within the website/webapp so it can be used by whatever the user already has going on). Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really about how to bundle and distribute a module to publish on npm for consumption by people building web apps. I would check out the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules/) on how that works on the publishing side, and check out Rollup or Webpack for documentation and examples on how to build libraries.

Comment: @ZacAnger Correct. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bundle client-side code and publish it through NPM you'll need to do a couple things: [learn how to package and publish modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/introduction-to-packages-and-modules), and write some code that can be consumed. This means using `module.exports` or `export` to expose your library, depending on whether you want to use CJS or ESM. The consumer of your library can usually be assumed to be using Webpack, Fuse, Rollup, or some other bundler which knows how to deal with modules.

You can also use a tool like Rollup yourself to build and bundle up your library for different targets and apply various transformations to it ([example from my own library boilerplate](https://github.com/zacanger/ts-library-boilerplate/blob/master/rollup.config.js)). Using a bundler like this makes more and more sense as your library inevitably grows larger.

Using modules like this rather than distributing through a CDN or in some other way that puts your library code on the global/window object is generally better for consumption in complex apps, large apps, and/or apps already being built with tools like Webpack (so, anything written in React, Angular, Vue, etc.). But having a CDN distribution is still a good idea for something like your library, since it may well be used by people building sites with jQuery and vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have some native JS code that uses WebRTC that I also bundle, will this work with that? The only reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering if this works with code that is native to the web, like RTCPeerConnection. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, webpack or rollup can definitely work for web-specific APIs. The configs might need some tweaking to avoid referenceerrors, and testing gets a little more complicated, but most folks building packages for the web are using a tool like Rollup or Webpack to bundle those libraries.