# How to publish a react app as on npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

OK, so I have a few js files in the form of auth.js, cookies.js, hooks.js, product.js, and index.js. What I want to do is to use npm to publish them as a package. MY index.js only exports all the other files with export * from './auth'
export * from './cookies'
export * from './hooks'
export * from './product'

I am running into some problems when trying to transpile to ES5 and then publish. Can you please point me to a guide that would help me accomplish this?

I have used npx-create-react-app to create this project.

The goal is to be able to npm -i  and then use functions from it with import {someFunctionInMyPackageName} from "my-package-name"

Comment: Does the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836589/bundle-and-publish-client-side-web-code-on-npm/65837534#65837534) help? Usually you would not publish an entire app, you would publish libraries, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes I am trying to publish an SDK that allows easy integration of a 3rd party software with react

Answer (score 0):

You can learn and read about either `rollup` or `webpack` to config and build to the library.

You can reference or use [this repo](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library) to create a library quickly.

Comment: thank you I will review it now. I was using webpack so far but ran into problems when trying to use a custom provider from the package.

Comment: I think use rollup is simpler than webpack. If you facing any trouble, you can ask new question.

Comment: Thank you I will try rollup and ask a new question if I run into trouble.